# How to make String indexes start at 1

Tags: java

I have a `String s = 'muniganesh'` and if I print the value of `s.subString(1, 2)`, the output is `'u'`, because in Java strings, the index starts at 0. But I need to change my string to start with index position 1. How is it possible?

Comment: Assuming `int startIndex` will be inside [1..s.length()], you could do `s.substring(startIndex-1, finish)`. Also, this `int finish` in the end of String#subString will be 1-index.

Comment: I have done that your suggestion already. But I need to know any solution for my scenario.

Comment: Edit your question showing the input and expected output to have a better understand of your needs. It would be better if you post more than 1 input/output sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your own utility method to process both #substring(start, end) arguments as zero-based indexes (or one-based indexes if you wish so), but as @irrelephant said it is not suggested, you should get accustomed to how Java handles these special cases: the first argument is **zero-based**, while the second one is **one-based**. `String#substring` is not the only example, there's also `StringBuilder#delete`, and there should be more.

The possible motivation could be calculating *end* position by simply adding **length** to the *start* position without additional increment. E.g.:

```
    String source = "In Java world, end position index may be one-based";
    int indexOfP = source.indexOf('p');
    String result = source.substring(indexOfP, indexOfP + 8);
    System.out.println(result); // prints 'position'
```

It's not the best example, and the true motivation may differ, but it's how I remember about this peculiarity.

Comment: The end index is not one-based. For example, 0 is a legal end index, which it wouldn't be if it was one-based. Both indexes are zero-based, but the end index is *exclusive*, whereas the begin index is inclusive.

Answer (score 6):

If you really really want to, you can write a method:

```
public static String substring(String str, int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    return str.substring(beginIndex - 1, endIndex - 1);
}
```

But I highly suggest you don't, since you might mix up `s.substring()` and your own `substring()` and get off by 1 errors. Just get accustomed to the way Java handles Strings, and use `s.substring()`. Many other popular languages start string indexes at 0 like Java.

Comment: the wrong part is the `endIndex - 1`. This value is 1-based index, while `beginIndex` is 0-based index.

Comment: The last two sentences are important here (the example could probably be scrapped). **Just get accustomed to the way Java handles Strings, and use `s.substring()`. Many other popular languages start string indexes at 0 like Java.**

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's not wrong. Both indexes are 0-based, which is why 0 is a legal value for the end index. However, the end index is exclusive, whereas the begin index is inclusive.

Comment: @Boann read the docs first. First index is 0 based, second index is 1 based.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You're wrong and that's not what the docs say.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
myString = myString.substring(1); // will give "uniganesh"
```

Answer (score 1):

Java string index starts from o an d ends up to string length -1.

so if you use

String s = "muniganesh";

```
s = s.substring(1,2);// output u


System.out.println(""+ s.substring(1)); //output String s = "muniganesh";
```

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays or strings (and the arrays of most other languages) index starting with 0. Make the string one longer and simply don't use the first index, or use indexes from 1 to string.length and simply subtract one when you actually index into the string.